# Maximum principle for $-\Delta u=(u-1)(u+1)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, elliptic-equations

> Consider a smooth solution that satisfies the elliptic equation
> $$-\Delta u=(u-1)(u+1)\  \text{ in }\ \{|x|<1\},\ \ u=f(x)\ \text{ on }\ |x|=1,$$
> where $f$ is a continuous function such that $-1<f(x)<1$ on $|x|=1$. Prove that $-1<u\le 1$ in $|x|<1$.

This question comes from [the qualify exam of UCLA](https://ww3.math.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ade-20F.pdf).

I can only prove that $u\geq-1$: if $u(x_0)=\min_{|x|\le 1}u<-1$, then $|x_0|<1$ and $\Delta u(x_0)\geq 0$, which leads into a contradiction with our original equation. But the similar argument fails for the upper bound of $u$, and I really don't know how to exclude the possibility of $\min_{|x|\le 1}u=-1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With $v=u-1$ very small, the equation should be well approximated by $-\Delta v=2v$. In one dimension that is solved by $v=\epsilon\cos \sqrt{2}x$. At the origin we have $v>0$. And if radius $r>\pi/(2\sqrt{2})$ then on the boundary of the "ball" (i.e. interval $[-r, r]$) we have $v<0$. This would seem to suggest that if the theorem is true (in one dimension) it depends on radius $r$ being sufficiently small! Strange

Comment: @Ali Thanks for your comment! I agree with you. It is strange.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is true. Just doing a quick numerical calculation in Mathematica with $n=1$, $f=0$ gives a function that appears to be approximately 3.4 units at $x=0$.

Comment: Here's the code if you want to double check: s = NDSolve[{-y''[x] == (y[x] - 1) (y[x] + 1), y[-1] == 0, y[1] == 0},
    y, {x, -1, 1}] ;
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]

Comment: Moreover, suppose that we did manage to prove $-1 \leqslant u \leqslant 1$. In this case $\Delta u \geqslant 0$ in $B_1$ so the strong maximum principle implies that $u<1$ so we in fact have $-1 \leqslant u <1$ instead of $-1<u\leqslant 1$. This doesn't contradict what they've written but it suggests to me that there might be an error

Comment: @JackT Thanks for your comments! You’re right and I’m convinced by you that the problem maybe problematic. I just wanted to find some nontrivial but not too hard exercises on maximum principle and I found this problem. So maybe I had a bad luck when I came across this problematic problem.

Comment: Following on from my earlier comment, it turns out the upper bound holds for any subsolution of the linear problem $Lv=\Delta v+2v\ge 0$ on a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ bounded by $|x_{1}|\le r$ for $r<\pi/(2\sqrt 2)$. If $g(x)=\cos\sqrt{2}\,x_{1}$ and $w=v/g$ then $Lv=\big(\Delta w + (2/g)\sum_{i}(\partial g/\partial x_{i})(\partial w/\partial x_{i})\big)\,g = g\,L'w$ with coefficients of $L'$ satisfying the weak maximum principle's conditions. So $\max_{\overline{\Omega}}w\le\max_{\partial\Omega}w< 0$ and $v< 0$ in $\Omega$. It's called the maximum principle for narrow domains.